# Replacing Whitespaces and Newlines with commas

Tags: php, regex

I have my `RegEx` here to replace both `whitespaces & newlines` with `,`.

```
preg_replace('#\s+#',',',trim($str));
```

The code works perfectly for the following case

```
$str = "
a
b
c
";
```

But if i wrote something like

```
$str = "
a,
b,
c
";
```

or

```
$str = "
a ,
b ,
c ,
";
```

i get for the first case `a,,b,,c` and in the second case `a,,,b,,,c`

I've tried using `strtr($str,',' => '')` before the `preg_replace()` but didn't work either, How can i handle this in the preg_replace directly?

My desired output is for all the values to be
`a, b, c, . . . .` If they have commas, it will be escaped since it already exists or be removed and cleaned and on and on, in the end only 1 comma separates them.

Comment: What is your dessired output?

Comment: In the one that's working perfectly, you should get `,a,b,c,` - is that what you actually want? The thing with Regular Expressions is that they expect something regular - if your input isn't going to be regular a RegExp might not be the best choice. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @Philipp Wrote it at the end of the question now.

Comment: @CD001 the `trim()` it solves the spaces problem at the beginning and the end. Wrote my desired goal at the end of the question.

Comment: @AXAI - oh yeah, missed the `trim()` sorry :)

Comment: Your `strtr()` call didn’t work because of incorrect syntax: see [here](https://3v4l.org/94s3J)

Comment: Try `preg_replace_callback('~^[\p{P}\s]+|[\p{P}\s]+$|([\p{P}\s]*\R\s*)~', function ($m) { return !empty($m[1]) ? "," : ""; }, $s)`

Comment: ^ I can't even be bothered to figure that out right now, but I've noticed @WiktorStribiżew seems to be a whizz with RegExps judging by previous answers/comments on here... so there's a good chance that'll work.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew It works, But wouldn't this be slower than a regular preg_replace?

Comment: @ishegg That solved it.

Comment: @AXAI I do not know the requirements, hence I posted a comment. The regex I mentioned will remove any 0+ punctuation and whitespaces, then a line break and then any whitespaces. Not sure you want exactly that. You may surely replace `\p{P}` with `,`. Or expand it with more punctuation/symbol chars. It is not that slower, it is still a one-regex pass, but you cannot replace with 2 different replacement patterns anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im not completly sure about your requirements, but you could try one of those

```
/[\s,]+$\n|[\s,]+/gm
```

or just

```
/[\s,]+/
```

Comment: Still gives addtional commas for spaces with a comma

Comment: Actually the second one gave me double the commas number.

Comment: Oh.. missed a char.. fixed it

Comment: Works perfectly now!

Comment: `/([\s\n,]+)/` will work the same as `/[\s,]+/` here. `\s` matches a newline, too.

Comment: @Philipp Is it possible to make it remove `,` if it is at the start or end alone or with a space?

Comment: just use `trim` to achieve this

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
$arr = explode("\r\n", $str);

array_walk($arr, function(&$item, $key)
{
    $item = rtrim($item,',');
    $item = trim($item);
});

$result = trim(implode(',', $arr), ',');


var_dump($result);
```

It is not a regex solution, but it works. This converts the string to array, removes commas and spaces and then converts array back to string and adds commas.

Comment: Works fine, But in case of performance, Wouldn't that take longer than a usual `preg_replace`? But stil works.

Comment: @AXAI Not necessarily, I ran some benchmarks and it shows that my solution faster than preg_replace. https://3v4l.org/70LPZ on some versions and on some `preg_replace` is faster.